# Where are the Eclipse CDT Debug Configurations stored?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I've got a C/C++ project with a custom debug configuration. That is, under Debug Configurations, I selected C/C++ Application and then hit the "New" button. I named this configuration MyTestingDebugConfiguration.

I've applied the changes and closed eclipse.

Where is this debug configuration named "MyTestingDebugConfiguration" stored? I don't see it listed in the .cproject file or the .project file. I'm assuming it is stored in xml somewhere on my filesystem. But I can't find it.

Note: My debug configuration points to a binary that is not in my project tree. I also declare an environment variable. I'd like to know where this configuration is stored on disk.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Launch configurations are stored in your workspace `.metadata` folder as ".launch" files, in

```
<workspace root>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core\.launches
```

Answer (score 0):

Mine was in this file:

> MyCppProject\.settings\language.settings.xml